# XML versus JSON for passing complete tree to decision based dynamic form on the UI

Tags: java, javascript, xml, json, xslt

Please deal with this naive question.

Objective is to create a UI and dynamically be able to change the basic workflows, add another option, add another steps etc.

As an example, one simple workflow could be as following:

1. What's the age of 'X'? TEXT_BOX
   if(age>18) proceed to step 2.
   else, go to next page (let's say, same processing happens again with different value of X).
2. What does 'X do? 
   a. Job
   b. Business

Submit (Go to next 'X').

I wanted to keep this workflow in XML as complete tree (all branches of if/else-if/else) and pass it on UI for rendering. Some of the sub-trees will be populated as per action performed in previous step.

This way, small modifications or workflow changes will not require any code changes.

Other option is to use JSON and pass it directly (rather than converting XML to JSON and passing) but it will be loosely coupled and could be difficult to manage in future.

Is there any clearcut benefit I should think of before choosing any of them?

Will any of them provide any extra benefit in the problem I am trying to solve?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to mimic the structure that you plan to have in an XML, as a json string, without any hurdles as far as I think of. (If you think of any hurdles please point out, I might help you out with idea to handle that).

json will for sure save you lots of bandwith if the data you are planning to send is large. This will inturn also reduce the roundtrip time and make your application more responsive.

Comment: Only issue I see is related with loose coupling but I agree to your point of application being more responsive. I was planning to send JSON to UI (by converting XML to JSON). Another option was to use XSLT to directly create HTML (I haven't evaluated it yet).

Hope I am clear. I wanted thoughts of someone who has already solved similar problem.